# How to get jQuery gallery to update when thumbnails are rolled over instead of clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, galleryview

I'm using the jQuery plugin [GalleryView](http://spaceforaname.com/galleryview) and current, when the thumbnails in the galllery are rolled over their opacity gradually becomes 100%, and when clicked, the main frame updates to reflect this thumbnail's image.

I'm trying to change it so that the main image is updated when the thumbnails are rolled over instead of having to be clicked, but I can't seem to find any parameters for this or find the relevent JavaScript inside the plugin to update this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The important bits happen in `enableFrameClicking()`, it looks like this:

```
function enableFrameClicking() {
  j_frames.each(function(i){
    if($('a',this).length==0) {
      $(this).click(function(){
        //.....
      });
    }
  });
}
```

To change the event for the thumbnails, you can change that [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) to a [`.mouseenter()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/).